# React Transferring Props except one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React suggests to [Transfer Props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#transferring-props-a-shortcut). Neat!

How can I transfer all of the props but one?

```
render: function(){
  return (<Cpnt {...this.propsButOne}><Subcpnt one={this.props.one} /></Cpnt>);
}
```

Comment: just pass all? no problem!

Comment: @DoubleU23 sometimes that can be serious problem!

Answer (score 204, accepted):

You can use the following technique to consume some of the props and pass on the rest:

```
render() {
  var {one, ...other} = this.props;
  return (
    <Cpnt {...other}>
      <Subcpnt one={one} />
    </Cpnt>
  );
}
```

[Source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html#transferring-with-...-in-jsx)

Comment: Had an issue with this, and was not able to solve it. Error Message:
`Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (7:19)` and the error message was highlighting the spread operator in the code.

`var {linkType, ...other} = this.props;`

Comment: Here's solution http://stefan.magnuson.co/articles/frontend/using-es7-spread-operator-with-webpack/

Comment: do you know what happens if you pass the same prop explicitly?  EG, if `other` contained a prop called `myProp` and you did something like this:

`<Cpnt {...other} myProp={123}>`.  Which value would `Cpnt` have for `myProp`?  Order dependent?

Comment: If you're getting Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, you probably need to add the babel rest spread transform plugin. See https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/

Comment: This would be the best solution but it's worth mentioning that destructuring assignments from objects using rest parameters is experimental. It should work using babel preset stage-2 for transpiling and when enabling "experimentalObjectRestSpread" under ecmaFeatures in your ESLint configuration (otherwise you can expect syntax errors like mentioned in other comments).

Answer (score 11):

What you need to do is to create a copy of the props object and delete the key(s) you don't want.
The easiest would be to use `omit` from `lodash` but you could also write a bit of code for this (create a new object that has all the keys of props except for one).

With omit (a few options at the top, depending on what package you import/ES flavor you use):

```
const omit = require('lodash.omit');
//const omit = require('lodash/omit');
//import { omit } from 'lodash';

...
render() {
    const newProps = omit(this.props, 'one');
    return <Cpnt {...newProps}><Subcpnt one={this.props.one} /></Cpnt>;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of props you don't want in `...rest` e.g. defaultProps, it can be annoying to write all of them twice. Instead you can create it yourself with a simple loop over the current props like that:

```
let rest = {};
Object.keys(this.props).forEach((key, index) => {
    if(!(key in MyComponent.defaultProps))
       rest[key] = this.props[key];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @villeaka!

Here's an example of how I used your solution for other people to better understand it's usage.

I basically used it to create a stateless wrapping-component that I then needed to pass its props to the inner component (Card).

I needed the wrapper because of the rendering logic inside another top level component that used this wrapper like this:

```
<TopLevelComponent>
  {/* if condition render this: */}
  <CardWrapper {...props}> {/* note: props here is TLC's props */}
    <Card {..propsExceptChildren}>
      {props.children}
    </Card>
  </CardWrapper>
  {/* if other condition render this: */}
  {/* ... */}
  {/* and repeat */}
</TopLevelComponent>
```

where several conditions determine what comes after the H4 in the wrapper (see actual rendered node tree below).

So basically, I didn't want to duplicate code by writing the entire part that comes before `{children}` in the example below, for each arm of the conditional in the top level component that renders multiple variants of the wrapper from above example:

```
const CardWrapper: React.FC<IRecentRequestsCardProps> = (props) => {
  const { children, ...otherProps } = props;
  return (
    <Card {...otherProps} interactive={false} elevation={Elevation.ONE}>
      <H4>
        <a href="/">Unanswered requests</a>
      </H4>
      {children}
    </Card>
  );
};
```

And concrete usage in a React render function:

```
if (error)
  return (
    <CardWrapper {...props}>
      <SimpleAlert title="Eroare" intent={Intent.DANGER}>
        {error}
      </SimpleAlert>
    </CardWrapper>
  );

if (loading)
  return (
    <CardWrapper {...props}>
      <NonIdealState
        icon="download"
        title="Vă rog așteptați!"
        description="Se încarcă cererile pentru articole..."
      />
    </CardWrapper>
  );

if (!data)
  return (
    <CardWrapper {...props}>
      <NonIdealState
        icon="warning-sign"
        title="Felicitări!"
        description="Nu există cereri fără răspuns."
      />
    </CardWrapper>
  );

// etc.
```

So the above just adds the H4 header before the children of the wrapper and also passes down the props that it has been passed down to, to the inner Card component.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I found so far:

```
const obj = {
  a: '1',
  b: '2',
  c: '3'
}

const _obj = {
  ...obj,
  b: undefined
}
```

This will result in `_obj` having all the props except `b`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function removeProps(obj, propsToRemove) {
   let newObj = {};
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
   if (propsToRemove.indexOf(key) === -1)
   newObj[key] = obj[key]
   })
   return newObj;
}

const obj = {nome: 'joao', tel: '123', cidade: 'goiania'}

const restObject = removeProps(obj, ['cidade', 'tel'])

console.log('restObject',restObject)

restObject
{
  nome:"joao"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when extending Material UI. A component would emit a warning if an unknown property was passed at all. I solved it slightly differently by specifically deleting the properties I didn't want to pass:

```
const passableProps = { ...props } as Partial<typeof props>;
delete passableProps.customValidity;
return (
    <TextField { ...passableProps } // ...
);
```