# Transfer { ..this.props } but exclude certain ones

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to transfer props down to child component where `{ ..this.props }` is used for cleaner easier syntax, however exclude certain props like `className` or `id`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Transferring Props except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152522/react-transferring-props-except-one)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't mind using a third-party library, you can also use lodash's `omit` function:

```
 { ..._.omit(this.props, ['className', 'id']) }
```

Key benefit: unlike madox2's suggestion, you don't pollute your scope with arbitrary variable names just to avoid passing certain props to child components. And also, at the time of writing this answer, you're not dealing with experimental ES.next features either.

Answer (score 54):

You can employ destructuring to do this job:

```
const { className, id, ...newProps } = this.props; // eslint-disable-line
// `newProps` variable does not contain `className` and `id` properties
```

Since this syntax is currently ECMAScript proposal (Rest/Spread Properties) you will need to transpile code to enable this feature (e.g. using babel).

Comment: This is amazing, but is there any easy way of not having eslint and the likes complain about an unused variable declaration using this pattern (other than disabling this rule)?

Comment: @madox this is good, but sort of requires me to manually process props, where as I want to take advantage of passing all of them down and only excluding ones I don't need as opposed to including ones I need

Comment: @m90 added comment which disables eslint for this particular line

Comment: @Ilja you would pass `newProps` down to the child, so `className` and `id` are the excluded ones. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @madox2 cool, I was just wondering if there is a way of configuring the rule in a way that it understands this, I will try to ask the issues on GitHub.

Comment: @TomFenech not necessarily, there can be other cases where className and id are not the only props, and it makes sense to exclude props as opposed to including them in my case, as only a couple should be disallowed, where others should be allowed.

Comment: @Ilja I'm not sure what you mean...I think that either you don't understand what the code is doing or we don't understand your requirement correctly. This will create three variables, `className`, `id` and `nextProps`, where `nextProps` is the object you want (I think?): it contains all the properties of `this.props`, but with `className` and `id` excluded. You would then pass `nextProps` to the child component.

Comment: This is react docs recomendation - https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html