# Deleting a key from an object does not work

Tags: reactjs

I have the following object

```
 this.state.books = {"test": "test1"}
```

I'm trying to delete a key from that object, but I'm not able to. Here's my code

```
 var books = Object.assign({}, this.state.books);
            delete books["test"];
            this.setState({
                books: books,
                loading: false
            });
```

setState is not triggering and rendering a new books object

Comment: What is bookId?

Comment: See new code above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove value from object without mutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053310/remove-value-from-object-without-mutation)

Answer (score 0):

you can use destructuring to delete the key.

```
const { test: gone, ...newBooks } = this.state.books
console.log('gone', gone);
console.log('newBooks', newBooks);

this.setState( prev => ({ ...prev, books: newBooks }))
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-sun-tec5v?file=/src/App.js)