# How to delete an empty property of an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, firebase, object

I'm new in JS and I want to delete the property "" of an object like this:

{tecnico2: 1.1, "": 0, tecnico4: 5, tecnico1: 3, tecnico3: 3}

to

{tecnico2: 1.1, tecnico4: 5, tecnico1: 3, tecnico3: 3}

Thank you for your time!!

I search about this but I only saw examples about delete the values '', not the key like I need it.

Comment: also [Remove value from object without mutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053310/remove-value-from-object-without-mutation) and a 14 year old duplicate [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {tecnico2: 1.1, "": 0, tecnico4: 5, tecnico1: 3, tecnico3: 3}

delete data['']

console.log(data)
```

or, if you don't want to modify the original data object:

```js
const data = {tecnico2: 1.1, "": 0, tecnico4: 5, tecnico1: 3, tecnico3: 3}

console.log(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).filter(([k])=>k!=='')))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const start = {tecnico2: 1.1, "": 0, tecnico4: 5, tecnico1: 3, tecnico3: 3}
        
const { ['']: empty, ...arrayWithoutKey } = start

console.log(arrayWithoutKey)
// { tecnico2: 1.1, tecnico4: 5, tecnico1: 3, tecnico3: 3 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.